# Passing value from data to variable

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, google-cloud-firestore

I'm currently using Ionic 4 and Firestore. I am trying to check if document id exist in Firestore, then do an if-else according to situation.

However, when I return the value and tried to assign it to a variable, it does not hold the value. Here is my sample code

```
this.service.checkLogin(this.test).then((data) => {
      this.testVar = data;
      console.log(this.testVar) //here shows 'false if data is false'

      if (testVar = true) {
        console.log(this.testVar) //however, over here it will show true 
                                    even if the result above was initally false. 
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/home');
      }
      else {

      };
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

In the line

```
if (testVar = true)
```

you're assigning to `testVar`, not testing whether it's true (you can do that using the == or === operators)

Also, there is no implicit `this` in javascript, so `this.testVar` is not the same variable as `testVar`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, where do you define your test var?
I think, it's `this.testVar`.

Then the way you test your variable is wrong.

**Single equal means assigning a value, not test it.**

You can do this, it will test everything different from `undefined` or `null`

```
if (this.testVar)
```

Or if you want to test if it's really a true value

```
if (this.testVar === true)
```

It will test the equality value, the `typeof` value (Boolean or whatever)